# "To service" vs. "to serve"

Tags: word-choice, verbs

I seem vaguely to recall that a long time ago, *servicing* was something a bull did to a heifer or a boar to a sow. But it seems to be creeping in to general usage as a synonym for *serving*. Has anyone else noticed this, and, if so, could they shed any light onto why this should be?

Comment: "Servicing" is also what a prostitute does to/for a client.  It's why I get a little wary any time a business I patronize refers to "servicing" its customers.

Comment: Yeah, the most common usage that jumped to mine was the one Boofus suggested I'm afraid!

Comment: Andrew M. Saul, new commissioner of the Social Security Administration, recently was quoted as saying "whatever we do from here on in, the SSA has to be for the benefit of our customers. WE ARE HERE TO SERVICE THEM."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've noticed it as well, and it usually makes me smile due to the distinct sexual connotation that people seem to have all but dropped. I think it just comes from "verbing the noun", honestly. "To service" is understood as "to provide a service to", which is effectively the same as "to serve".

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it something like "servicing" is a technical term meaning maintenance & repair while "serving" is a business term meaning giving a certain service to a customer, as in the service industry. Do I remember wrong?

Comment: We do prefer answers that aren't questioning their own accuracy.