# Is the usage of "service" as a verb a recent phenomenon?

Tags: etymology

I am finding that people use the word "serviced" in place of other verbs such as *served, repaired, helped*, etc. Has the use of the word service always been acceptable as a verb? Or is that a more recent phenomenon?

Comment: Now you've done it.  Made be think of "memorial service" as used in *Giles Goat-Boy*.

Comment: Related: ['Services' or 'Serves'?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4551/services-or-serves)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the use of *service* as a verb is not particularly recent. The OED’s earliest citation in support of the meaning ‘to be of service to; to serve; to provide with a service’ is this in a book by Robert Louis Stevenson in 1893:

> If I am to service ye the way that you propose, I'll lose my
>   lifelihood.

Answer (score 3):

*Service* as a verb is not uncommon. For example,

> These appliances are **serviced** regularly.

ODO says of the verb *[service](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/service)*

> The early sense of the verb (mid 19th century) was 'be of service to,
>   provide with a service'

Answer (score 3):

It depends what you mean by "recent". There are plenty of examples starting from the 1920's of *"to service"* in the sense of to perform a [regular] maintenance procedure on something "mechanical" (often, a car). It doesn't seem to have been used that way often, if at all, any earlier.

Back in the 1800s, *"to service"* was sometimes used to mean *"to serve"* in various senses (serve in a military capacity, to be of use, to provide with a service, to attend to someone's needs, etc.), but I think the modern usage is probably better described as [verbification](http://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&q=verbification&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&sa=X&psj=1&ei=d3RnT8ixPIzH8gOCzeS_Bg&ved=0CCAQkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=83e001d13871f6c4&biw=1290&bih=902) from the newly-emerging sense of *maintenance of mechanisms*. I'm sure there are earlier instances, but [here, for example](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=80cPAQAAIAAJ&q=%22engine%20service%22&dq=%22engine%20service%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=83RnT_2cBIKp8QOkt_GlCA&ved=0CGsQ6AEwBjgK) is a link to the *Report of the Proceedings of the Annual Convention of the American Railway Master Mechanics' Association (1899)* where I note that one reference to **engine-service** is hyphenated, but two others not - which strongly suggests that specific usage was "new and unusual" at the time.

I do not recognise OP's *served* and *helped* as synonyms of *serviced* in any modern context.